# Calculate date variance based on common id

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large table that looks like the following:

```
+---+---------+----------+-------+---------+------------+
|   | cust_id | order_id | quant | revenue |    date    |
+---+---------+----------+-------+---------+------------+
| 0 |  103502 |   107801 |     1 | 246.5   | 2014-07-15 |
| 1 |  110301 |   108001 |     2 | 106.0   | 2014-07-15 |
| 2 |  110301 |   108101 |     2 | 106.0   | 2014-07-15 |
| 3 |  111401 |   108201 |     2 | 408.5   | 2014-07-15 |
| 4 |  111502 |   108301 |     1 | 196.0   | 2014-07-15 |
+---+---------+----------+-------+---------+------------+
```

For customers that purchase more than once (same cust_id), I am trying to group the data together to find the earliest and latest date for each.  For example, say cust_id 123456 purchases on 2014-6-30 and 2013-6-30.  For my scenario I would like an output of 365 days.

Is this something I would use `groupby` for and then apply a function to it?  I tried doing a `groupby` for the cust_id and date columns, but I was given an object so I'm not sure if it is formatted properly.

Comment: Have you read the tutorial section, [Group By: split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)? It shows you how to view the grouped information, and how to accomplish what you're trying to do. It's a lot better than just randomly calling functions and hoping one of them is right.

Comment: I did look at it, but I had some difficulty translating it into what I am trying to do.  I will revisit. Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, it would help to give the sample input in a form that people can copy and paste into the interactive interpreter (or paste into a script, or save in a file and read with `pd.load`, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's start off with what `groupby` does.

(I changed your data to give you different dates, because it's not very interesting if they're all the same.)

```
>>> d={'cust_id': (103502,110301,110301,111401,111502),
...    'order_id': (107801,108001,108101,108201,108301), 
...    'quant': (1,2,2,2,1), 
...    'revenue': (246.5,106.0,106.0,408.5,196.0), 
...    'date': [datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d') for dt in 
...             ('2014-07-15', '2014-07-16', '2014-07-17', '2014-07-18', '2014-07-19')]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
   cust_id       date  order_id  quant  revenue
0   103502 2014-07-15    107801      1    246.5
1   110301 2014-07-16    108001      2    106.0
2   110301 2014-07-17    108101      2    106.0
3   111401 2014-07-18    108201      2    408.5
4   111502 2014-07-19    108301      1    196.0
>>> gb = df.groupby('cust_id')
>>> gb.groups
{111401: [3], 111502: [4], 110301: [1, 2], 103502: [0]}
```

This is pretty clear: each cust_id has a group of associated rows.

So, what can we do with this? Well, just as you can access a DataFrame's columns to get Series, you can access a DataFrameGroupBy's columns to get SeriesGroupBy. And then you call aggregate methods on those columns, which gives you a single value for each group:

```
>>> gb['date'].max()
cust_id
103502     2014-07-15
110301     2014-07-17
111401     2014-07-18
111502     2014-07-19
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So, what (I think) you want is:

```
>>> gb['date'].max() - gb['date'].min()
cust_id
103502    0 days
110301    1 days
111401    0 days
111502    0 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It is very helpful.  Out of curiosity, let's day date remains in the 5th column, not the 2nd column.  Would I need to use the `axis` attribute somewhere?

Comment: In general, the order of columns is not important in pandas. You generally reference them using their name-  df['column_name']. In your case, if the date column appeared second, or fifth, it would not matter in the code above.

Comment: @Meepl: Notice that I listed it fifth in the `dict` display used to build the `DataFrame`. Of course `dict`s are ordered arbitrarily, but because I planned to refer to the column by name, I didn't care about the order and didn't even notice it was second rather than fifth. That demonstrates how little the order matters—after you get the hang of things, you don't even see it…

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting these data from a database table, and that table name is t1, the following query will give the date difference.

```
select t1.cust_id,max(t2.date)-min(t1.date) from t1, t1 as t2 where t1.cust_id=t2.cust_id group by t1.cust_id;
```

Comment: But this is a Pandas DataFrame, not a SQL database table, so that doesn't really help much.

Comment: Sorry about that. My mistake.